# PHP GET and Load in a div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a new structure getting a date, then connect to a php file... The jquery documentation is followed to the letter, now I need to get the PHP file to GET the date, then select the data from mysql table and put it into the div waiting for it.

Here is the Jquery script...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {   
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));

   $('#apDiv2').load('dayPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
            $('#apDiv4').load('dayGraph.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
            $('#apDiv6').load('monthPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
            $('#apDiv9').load('monthGraph.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
            $('#apDiv8').load('yearPower.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
            $('#apDiv10').load('yearGraph.php', {choice: dateText}, function() {
                  $(this).show();
            });
      }});
});
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?  
$choice = (isset($_GET['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mackie1604");  
if (!$con)  {  
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  

$sql = 'SELECT sum(power) AS choice '         
.'FROM feed '        
.'WHERE date = \'$choice\' '; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
echo $row['choice'], '<br />';  
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

WHy wont the php work ?

Comment: What does "Won't work" mean? What errors are you getting in the server logs/ What errors are you getting in the JS console? Look at the requests being made — are the URLs right? Look at the responses, is PHP outputting what you want?

Comment: @David Dorward, maybe I´m missing something, but the only `$_GET` variable I see, is used in the `date` function so that should't be a problem, should it? Anyway, using `root` as your mysql user seems a bit overkill as well.

Comment: Hello, The root is just for my testing server, not online.

Comment: @jeroen — oops, I missed that bit.

Comment: If you are sending the same data (the `choice=dateText` bit) to the server, you may be better off having a single PHP script, which takes that parameter, does all the required work, and the returns a JSON object containing the content for each of the affected DIVs. So you could call it using the `$.get()` or `$.post()` jQuery functions, and then, in the success handler, extract the bits and change the `.html()` of the affected elements as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is how your entire code should look like

http://pastie.org/1341230

Comment: That gives me an output of '; ?> in the div,

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much for your help... now I just have to get the SELECT for the Month and the Year.

Answer (score 0):

Then you pass an object to [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it's a POST, not a GET request.
[From the documentation for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

So on the PHP side, you would need to replace:

```
$_GET['choice']
```

With:

```
$_POST['choice']
```

You have other errors as well, but the basic starting reason it won't work is because you're not getting the variable you're after.  You should fix the SQL injection vulnerability and the year formatting for other cultures as well (if needed).

Comment: in the doc it says .load is equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) doesn't it mean that it use get to request?

Comment: @Breezer - I linked the documentation :) It notes that a `POST` is used if `data` is an object...you can see the code here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L49

Comment: oh didn't know, well you learn something new everyday don't ya :) thx anywaays

Comment: Or you could just append the `choice=dateText` bit to the end of the requested filename, so request `'dayPower.php?choice='+escape(dateText)` rather than just `'dayPower.php'`

Comment: @Lucanos - You should not use `escape()`, it's deprecated you should use `escapeURIComponent()` instead :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Showing my javascript age, I guess. Cheers for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes:

```
$sql = 'SELECT sum(power) AS choice '         
.'FROM feed '        
.'WHERE date = \'$choice\' ';
```

So your `$choice` variable will not be used, the query will see it literally as `$choice`.

A solution for this specific problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(power) AS choice "         
."FROM feed "        
."WHERE date = '$choice' ";
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the fast feedback... still don't get why it does not work.

Comment: Do you get the query you want if you do a `var_dump($sql)`?